# CodeIgniter Passing POST data from RestClient to RestServer API("SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data")

Tags: codeigniter, jira-rest-api

I've spent my whole day trying to figure out this problem. Posting this issue here is my last hope. I hope someone can help to continue working on my first job.

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

So, POST works fine when directly passing data from my views to the RestServer directly. However, RESTServer API is not able to find POSTs data sent from the RestClient.

my Example

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';



class Example extends REST_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->methods['get']['limit'] = 500; 
        $this->methods['post']['limit'] = 200;
        $this->methods['delete']['limit'] = 50; 
    }



    public function post()
    {

            $message = array(
                'id' => null,
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'message' => $this->input->post('email')
            ); 

        $this->set_response($message); 
    }


}
```

Comment: Try with different name like `index_post()`. [Docs](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver#handling-requests).

Comment: we can change but Show the Following error

Comment: status false
error "Unknown method"

Answer (score 0):

**First off:**, try renaming your POST function from `post()` to `index_post()` that is simply a standard that can help with SOLID principles.

**Second:**
Is there in your Controller somewhere whare you put the `use CI_Controller` namespace either you added it in the `REST_Controller.php` file, since it is not in the `Example` controller; just **REMOVE** that namespace. The below 3 requirements should work just fine for you.

```
require(APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php');
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
require (APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php');

class Example extends REST_Controller { 
... 
}
```